# Move files to specific folders based on 7th character of filename

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move recently renamed files from a Temp folder to a destination folder based on the filenames 7th character.

For example every filename's 7th Character is the size of the drawing. So what I am trying to do is if the filename's 7th chr is = A then move the file to "...\A-SIZE_8.5X11" folder.

*Note that the MainDir is created from the autocad script when it prints a PDF.

Currently I am getting an error at `If Mid(Dir(s, vbDirectory), x).Value = "A" Then` Says Type Mismatch.
Any feedback is much appreciated.

```
Sub MoveFiles()
Dim s As String, x As String
Dim LoginName As String, MainDir As String, 
SourceDir As String
Dim destDirA As String, destDirB As String, 
destDirC As String, destDirD As String

LoginName = UCase(GetUserID)
MainDir = "C:\Users\" & LoginName & "\Desktop\PDF\"
SourceDir = MainDir & "_Temp\"
destDirA = MainDir & "A-SIZE_8.5X11"
destDirB = MainDir & "B-SIZE_11X17"
destDirC = MainDir & "C-SIZE_17X22"
destDirD = MainDir & "D-SIZE_24X36"

s = (SourceDir & "\*.pdf?")
x = Mid(s, 7, 1) 'Find letter after S-000-

If Mid(Dir(s, vbDirectory), x).Value = "A" Then
    If Len(Dir(destDirA, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir destDirA
        Do
        Name SourceDir & s As destDirA & s & "\" & s
    Loop Until s = ""
End If

If Mid(Dir(s, vbDirectory), x).Value = "B" Then
    If Len(Dir(destDirB, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir destDirB
        Do
        Name SourceDir & s As destDirB & s & "\" & s
    Loop Until s = ""
End If

If Mid(Dir(s, vbDirectory), x).Value = "C" Then
    If Len(Dir(destDirC, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir destDirC
        Do
        Name SourceDir & s As destDirC & s & "\" & s
    Loop Until s = ""
End If

If Mid(Dir(s, vbDirectory), x).Value = "D" Then
    If Len(Dir(destDirD, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir destDirD
        Do
        Name SourceDir & s As destDirD & s & "\" & s
    Loop Until s = ""
End If
End Sub
```

Modified If statements so loop ends before Dir is called again. Found part of this code online and tried modifying it to work but im not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I don't see a question or problem? Does this run? Doe it error out? Does it run but nothing seems to happen? Does it run and you get unexpected results?

Comment: You cannot use `Dir()` in a nested way - each loop needs to complete before you call `Dir()` for another purpose.  Also you seem to have a bunch of extra `Do`'s in there.

Comment: It errors at `If Mid(Dir(s, vbDirectory), x).Value = "A" Then` says Type Mismatch.

Comment: The problem as I see it is that you set the variable `x` here: `x = Mid(s, 7, 1) 'Find letter after S-000-`. Presumably the value in `x` is some letter after 'S-000-'. Next, you pass this variable `x` (a letter) as the second argument to the `mid` function here: `If Mid(Dir(s, vbDirectory), x).Value = "A"`. The second parameter to the `mid` function should be a number. I'm not so sure what you want to happen there, but hopefully this info helps you move in the right direction.

Comment: Your `Do` loops in the modified code have no way to exit - the value of `s` is never changed inside the loop.  Luckily, you'll never *enter* the loops because `Mid` returns a `Variant` containing a `String`, which doesn't have `.Value` member, so the run-time error 424 will prevent this from putting Excel into a non-responsive state.

Comment: If anyone would like to comment with working code I would gladly gift bounty points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the below example:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestShellApp()

    Dim sSourceFolder As String
    Dim sTargetFolder As String
    Dim sSourcePattern
    Dim sTargetPath As String
    Dim oShellApp
    Dim oSourceFolder
    Dim oSourceFolderItems
    Dim oTargetFolder
    Dim sKey

    sSourceFolder = "C:\Test\Source\"
    sTargetFolder = "C:\Test\Target\"

    Set oShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oSourceFolder = oShellApp.Namespace((sSourceFolder))
    Set oSourceFolderItems = oSourceFolder.Items()
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .Item("A") = "A-SIZE_8.5X11"
        .Item("B") = "B-SIZE_11X17"
        .Item("C") = "C-SIZE_17X22"
        .Item("D") = "D-SIZE_24X36"
        For Each sKey In .Keys
            sTargetPath = sTargetFolder & .Item(sKey)
            SmartCreateFolder sTargetPath
            Set oTargetFolder = oShellApp.Namespace((sTargetPath))
            For Each sSourcePattern In Array( _
                    "??????" & sKey & "*", _
                    "????????" & sKey & "*" _
                )
                oSourceFolderItems.Filter 32 + 64 + 128, sSourcePattern
                oTargetFolder.MoveHere oSourceFolderItems, 16 + 1024
            Next
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox "Files moved"

End Sub

Sub SmartCreateFolder(sFolder)

    Static oFSO As Object

    If oFSO Is Nothing Then Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With oFSO
        If Not .FolderExists(sFolder) Then
            SmartCreateFolder .GetParentFolderName(sFolder)
            .CreateFolder sFolder
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How could I add onto this and also move files that contain the same `.Item Key but in the 9th position?

Comment: @MattTaylor Just add a nested loop, check the answer.